# How to achieve cache coherency with an abstract class pointer vector in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, caching, polymorphism

I'm making a little game in C++. I found answers on StackExchange sites about cache coherency, and I would like to use it in my game, but I'm using child classes of an abstract class, Entity.

I'm storing all entities in a std::vector so that I can access virtual functions in loops. **Entity::update() is a virtual function of Entity overridden by subclasses like PlayerEntity.**

In Game.hpp - Private Member Variables:

```
std::vector<Entity*> mEntities;
PlayerEntity* mPlayer;
```

In Game.cpp - Constructor:

```
mPlayer = new PlayerEntity();
mEntities.push_back(mPlayer);
```

Here's what my update function (in the main loop) looks like:

```
void Game::update() {
  for (Entity* entity : mEntities) {
    entity->update(mTimeStep, mGeneralClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds());
  }
}
```

My question is:
**How do I make my entities objects be next to each other in memory, and thus achieve cache coherency?**
I tried to simply make the vector of pointers a vector of objects and make the appropriate changes, but then I couldn't use polymorphism for obvious reasons.
Side question: what determines where an object in allocated in memory?
Am I doing the whole thing wrong? If so, how should I store my entities?

Note: I'm sorry if my english is bad, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I think you'll have to use a "native" array in order to keep all your instances consecutive in memory (BTW, I don't see what this question has to do with polymorphism).

Comment: The problem with a native array is that I can't make it grow or shrink, and entities spawn and disappear often in a game. Regarding polymorphism: I can't just store objects in the vector because if I did so I wouldn't be able to access virtual methods of the entities, like update in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, first measure which parts are even worth optimizing. Not all games are created equal, and not all code within a game is created equal. There is no use in completely restructuring the script that triggers the end boss's death animation to make it use 1 cache line instead of 2. That said...

If you are aiming for optimizing for cache, forget about inheritance and virtual functions. Or at least be critical of them. As you note, creating a contiguous array of polymorphic objects is somewhere between hard & error-prone and completely infeasible (depending on whether subclasses have different sizes).

You can attempt to create a pool, to have nearby entities (in the entities vector) more likely to be close to each other (in memory), but frankly I doubt you'll do much better than a state of the art general-purpose allocator, especially when the entities' size and lifetime varies significantly. A pool would only help if entities adjacent in the vector are allocated back-to-back. But in that case, any standard allocator gives the same locality advantages. It's not like `tcmalloc` and friends select a random cache line to allocate from just to annoy you.

You might be able squeeze a bit of memory out of knowing your object types, but this is purely hypothetical and would have to be proven first to justify the effort of implementing it. Also note that a run of the mill pool either assumes that all objects  are the same size, or that you never deallocate individual objects. Allowing both puts you halfway towards a general-purpose allocator, which you're bound to do worse.

You can segregate objects based on their types. That is, instead of a single vector with polymorphic `Entity`s with virtual functions, have N vectors: `vector<Bullet>`, `vector<Monster>`, `vector<Loot>`, and so on. This is less insane than it sounds for threereasons:

1. Often, you can pull out the entire business of managing one such vector into a dedicated system. So in the end you might even have a `vector<System *>` where each `System` has a vector for one kind of thing, and updates all those things in a single virtual call (delegating to many statically-dispatched calls).
2. You don't need to represent *everything ever* in this abstraction. Not every little integer needs to be wrapped in its own type of entity.
3. If you go further down this route and take hints from entity component systems, you also gain an alternative to inheritance for code reuse (`class Monster : Entity {}; class Skeleton : Monster {};`) that plays nicer with the hard-earned cache friendliness.

Comment: Problem solved, I'll do as you say. I've been looking for a solution like yours for quite a lot of time, because every time I wanted to add a parameter to the `update` method of `PlayerEntity`, I had to add it to `Entity` too. I know this would have become cumbersome to manage after a while. That said, I don't understand what you said at the end of your post about entity component systems.

Comment: @filsmick [ECS](http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/es-tutorials) is a paradigm that takes "composition over inheritance" to its logical extreme. The "entities" of the game become nothing more than a bit of glue holding together various components, where each component corresponds to some bit of data or logic (depending on the variation - you can have logic in the components, or put the logic into separate "systems" or "processors").

Comment: Wait, I realize I still have a little question. If I use a vector for each entity type, will the entities in it always be contiguous in memory? Example: `mSkeletons.push_back(SkeletonEntity())`  
Will this skeleton be next to the other skeletons in memory?  
@delnan I read about it, but I didn't see how to implement it. Do you have another link where I can learn ECS? This one doesn't seem very straightforward.

Comment: @filsmick Yes, a vector stores by value/without indirection. As for implementing ECS, see http://t-machine.org/index.php/2014/03/08/data-structures-for-entity-systems-contiguous-memory/ and http://www.randygaul.net/2013/05/20/component-based-engine-design/ for starters. But there's not even a single canonical design, much less a single right way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks @delnan. So the new SkeletonEntity will be moved into the vector rather than copied into it?

Comment: @filsmick Whether it's moved or copied is another thing (I assume you use "move" in the standard C++11 sense). `emplace_back` moves, `push_back` copies. Both move/copy to a location inside the vector's contiguous storage, next to the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy because polymorphism doesn't work well with cache coherency.

I think the best you can overload the base class new operator to allocate memory from a pool.  But to do this, you need to know the size of all derived classes and after some allocating/deallocating you can have memory fragmentation which will lower the gain.

Comment: So, basically, I have to learn to make memory pools? Would they add a lot of extra complexity to my code?

Comment: Yes, it is not simple and it doesn't add functionality.  I would only use it if I know it is really needed (or for educational reasons).

Comment: And won't it be a huge performance loss to leave things as they are? (look at my code)

Comment: Performance loss compared to what?  Looping over containers, calling a virtual function is done a lot, usually not with performance issues.

Comment: Compared to a vector of objects contiguous in memory.

Comment: You still need to do the same things.  Polymorphism is about dispatching, not just accessing.  And besides, if your objects are not of the same size, there is no way, you can have a vector/array of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html), it's a tool that  simulates how your program interacts with a machine's cache hierarchy.

Comment: At best, Cachegrind tells you how well or not the cache is used, but it doesn't tell how you to make it use the cache well. This question is about the latter.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to do this: http://supercomputingblog.com/optimization/taking-advantage-of-cache-coherence-in-your-programs/ with pointers to instances of a child of an abstract class.

Comment: Yes @delnan, that's exactly what I'm asking.